# OrderBy from relationship, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a table of Questions, where I use:

```
    $query->orderBy($request->sort_by, ($request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc');
   //sort_by and sort_direction are from front-end, and this works for my main table
```

But in that table I have 2 relationships, and I want to sort by a column from the table that has a relationship, also to sort by a count of that.

Ex: a Question has many answer_history, each answer_history has a answer_type column ('none' or 'skipped') I want to sort by count(answer_type = 'none').

[image]

```
$query = Question::select(['id', 'free_text', 'title', 'best_match',  'created_at']);
$query->with('answer_history');
$query->with(['bestMatch']);
$query->orderBy($request->sort_by, ($request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc');
return response()->json($query->paginate($request->per_page));
//this works just for main table
```

**UPDATE:**

```
if($request->sort_by){
   if($request->sort_by === 'best_match'){
      $query->orderBy(function ($bestMatch, $key) {
            return count($bestMatch['name']);
      },($request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc');
   }else{
    $query->orderBy($request->sort_by, ($request->sort_direction === 'false') ? 'asc' : 'desc');
   }
}
// I tried to do this for a column from best_match, but is not working
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the check on the relationship when you lazy load it.

```
->with(['bestMatch' => function ($query) use ($request){
      if($request->sort_by && $request->sort_by === 'best_match') {
          $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
      }
   }
])
```

You can do same for the 'answer_history'.

**Note:** Code is not tested.